# tr:validateDateTimeRange, validation error on selecting current date when setting max date as current date

Tags: jsf, myfaces, trinidad

I Use Trinidad 2.1 and using tr:validateDateTimeRange to set maximum date in trinidad input date tag,

```
<tr:inputDate id="frmCal" value="#{reportsBackingBean.reportsModel.searchFromDt}">                                      
<tr:validateDateTimeRange maximum="#{reportsBackingBean.maxDate}" />
```

Here reportsBackingBean.maxDate refers current date and in date picker when i select current date and submit the form it shows validation error "The date must be on or before 17/09/2015".
Is this the actual behavior? I need current date should be accepted. Please help

Comment: Can you try again after setting the context parameter (web.xml) `javax.faces.DATETIMECONVERTER_DEFAULT_TIMEZONE_IS_SYSTEM_TIMEZONE` to `true`?

Comment: @JasperdeVries Thanks. I added this in `javax.faces.DATETIMECONVERTER_DEFAULT_TIMEZONE_IS_SYSTEM_TIMEZONE` in web.xml but the same error message is displayed. So i set getActualMaximum `Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();cal.setTime(searchFromDt);cal.set(cal.get(Calendar.YEAR),cal.get(Calendar.MONTH),cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH), cal.getActualMaximum(Calendar.HOUR), cal.getActualMaximum(Calendar.MINUTE),cal.getActualMaximum(Calendar.SECOND));searchFromDt = cal.getTime();`
for both searchFromDt and maxDate. Now both of having the same value **Sep 17 11:59:59 EDT 2015**. Even then,no luck.

Comment: Apparently maximum is not inclusive? I'm not familiar with Trinidad, but I'd expect to see this being answered in tag documentation.

Answer (score 1):

MyFaces has changed its implementation for validateDateTimeRange. You have to give the maximum values for 'hours, minutes, seconds, milliseconds'.
Try this:

```
<code>Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.setTime(maxDate);
cal.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 23);
cal.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 59);
cal.set(Calendar.SECOND, 59);
cal.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 59);
maxDate = cal.getTime();
</code>
```

`Note:` maxDate is the variable which you have it in reportsBackingBean.

https://myfaces.apache.org/trinidad/trinidad-api/tagdoc/tr_validateDateTimeRange.html